# Relationship bridges in DBIC

Tags: dbix-class

I have several bridges in one Result class, which have a relationship with the same *another* Result class. For example in a **Text** class I have several bridges to the **User** class.
So then, they will be named by default something like **users** and **users_2s**. I can remap those names with a rel_name_map option, but the question is whether there is any semantic behind those namings? How is it decided which one will be named **users** and which one will be named **users_2s**? Maybe if I create tables in another order on another machine the relationships will be named in another order and the **users** will become **users_2s** and vice versa?
If I use rel_name_map and decide to rename them can I be sure that the order will be always preserved?

Comment: Are you using DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader to generate the DBIx::Class schema? Note that the abbreviation for DBIx::Class is DBIC, not DBIx which is a whole namespace including many different dists.

Comment: Yes, I use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: The database already has names for the bridges, and DBIx::Class will use those names. So you're safe from having them being renamed between runs so long as you aren't changing your database between runs.

If you look at your database with the right tools/commands you should see the names "users" and "user_2s" already associated with those bridges. Each "bridge" is a foreign key constraint, and as such has a name in your source database schema. The library function `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::DBI::_table_fk_info` calls the DBD handler's foreign_key_info method to get the bridges, and uses the given name.

If the handler doesn't return foreign-key names then it **will** generate a new name, using this format: `__dcsld__$i`, where `$i` is a number starting at 1.  The numbering will only change if the in-database schema changes.

That `dscld` stands for `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader`- and it doesn't match your bridge names, so your code must be getting those names from the database.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your reply. I guess I didn't formulate my question very clearly, so here I go again: both of my bridges have foreign key part with identical name 'user' and both point to the same table. I have a conflict here. So I program, that the default bridge name for first bridge suggested by schema loader should map to 'my_name', then the second bridge maps automatically to 'my_name_2s', which I say should map to 'his_name'. So my question is whether I can be sure, that 'my_name' will always map to the first suggested bridge and 'his_name' to the second on every machine where I create it?